# Scala (NOT pyspark) map linear regression coefficients to feature names (categorical and continuous)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, encoding, regression, categorical-data

I have a dataframe in scala that looks like this

```
df.show
+---+-----+-------------------+--------+------------------+--------+------+------------+-------------+
| id|group|  normalized_amount|query_id|                 y|      y1|group1|groupIndexed| groupEncoded|
+---+-----+-------------------+--------+------------------+--------+------+------------+-------------+
|  1|    B|   0.22874172014806|       1| 0.317739988492575|       0|     B|         1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
|  2|    A|  -1.42432215217563|       2| -1.32008967486074|       0|     C|         0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|  3|    B|  -2.03644548423379|       3| -1.65740392834359|       0|     B|         1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
|  4|    B|  0.425753803902096|       4|-0.127591370989296|       0|     C|         0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|  5|    A|  0.521050829955076|       5| 0.824285664580579|       1|     A|         2.0|    (2,[],[])|
|  6|    A|-0.0416682439998418|       6| 0.321350404322885|       1|     C|         0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|  7|    A|   -1.2787327462978|       7| -0.88099379032367|       0|     A|         2.0|    (2,[],[])|
|  8|    A|  0.431780409975322|       8| 0.575249966796747|       1|     C|         0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
```

And I'm performing a linear regression of `y` on `group1` (a categorical variable of 3 categories) and `normalized_amount` (a continuous variable) as follows

```
var assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("groupEncoded", "normalized_amount")).setOutputCol("features")
val dfFeatures = assembler.transform(df)
var lr = new LinearRegression()
var lrModel = lr.fit(dfFeatures)
var lrPrediction = lrModel.transform(dfFeatures)
```

I can access coefficients and standard errors as follows

```
lmModel.intercept
lrModel.coefficients //model coefficient estimates (not intercept)
lrModel.summary.coefficientStandardErrors //standard error of intercept and coefficients, not sure in which order
```

My questions are

1. how can I figure out which feature correspond to which coefficient estimate (for categorical values, I need to figure out the coefficient of each category)? Same with standard errors?
2. how can I choose which category to "leave out" as the reference category?
3. how to perform a linear regression with no intercept?

I've seen some answers to similar questions, but they are all in pyspark and not in scala, and I'm only using scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a dataframe as your transformed df, that includes the prediction, and LogisticRegressionModel, you can access to the attributes of the VectorAssembler field. This code from [databricks](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5211178207246023/3527163800997788/7788830288800223/latest.html), I slightly adapted it for a LogisticRegressionModel instead of Pipeline. Note that you can choose if you want intercept estimation or not:

```
val lrToFit : LinearRegression = ???
lrToFit.setFitIntercept(false)

// With this dataframe as your transformed df that includes the prediction
val df: DataFrame = ???
val lr : LogisticRegressionModel = ???
val schema = df.schema

// Using the schema, the attributes of the Vector Assembler(features) can be extracted
val features = AttributeGroup.fromStructField(schema(lr.getFeaturesCol)).attributes.get.map(_.name.get)
val featureNames: Array[String] = if (lr.getFitIntercept) {
  Array("(Intercept)") ++ features
} else {
  features
}

val coefficients = lr.coefficients.toArray
val coeffs = if (lr.getFitIntercept) {
  coefficients ++ Array(lr.intercept)
} else {
  coefficients
}

featureNames.zip(coeffs).foreach { case (feature, coeff) =>
  println(s"$feature\t$coeff")
}
```

This is a method that can be used if you load a pretrained model because in that case you might not know the order of the features in the VectorAssembler transformation. I think that you will need to select the reference category manually.

Comment: how should I select the reference category?